# "I like number 2 and 3" or "I like numbers 2 and 3"?

Tags: grammatical-number, ellipses

What is the **correct form** and what is the **exact name** of this phenomenon. I tried looking it up myself but I could only find a [German explanation](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4000/singular-plural-bei-aufzahlungen) that might also explain the English problem.

An example could be:

> Please read page 1 and 2

vs

> Please read pages 1 and 2

or

> I like number 2 and 3

vs

> I like numbers 2 and 3

and another one:

> I managed to solve question 6, 7, 8 and 9

vs

> I managed to solve questions 6, 7, 8 and 9

Comment: I think a little more context than just "page 1+2" would be helpful. Could you edit the question to give complete sentences and put the relevant part in bold? Do use the word *and* if that's what you mean rather than a plus sign.

Comment: ok, edited the question and the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are noticing something called *ellipsis*. The correct way to say these would be

> Do problems 1 and 2.
>   Do problem 1 and problem 2.

However, you can shorten "problem 1 and problem 2" to leave out the second instance of the repeated word "problem", getting:

> Do problem 1 and 2.

There are only some cases in which you can do this. I would say this case is borderline.

This has nothing to do with the German link, which is talking about constructions like

> Macaroni and cheese is my favorite meal.
>   Thunder and lightning is scary.

where two paired words which occur together often are treated as a singular construct.

Comment: Thank you, the longer I think about it ellipsis seems to be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If by “+” you mean “and”, then you want the plural.  E.g.:

> Do problems 2 and 3 from chapters 4 and 5 on pages 127 and 128.

Comment: You can also use the singular. "Do problem 2 and 3" is an instance of *ellipsis* ... it's short for "Do problem 2 and problem 3".

Comment: I have difficulty eliding _problem_ here, unless I imagine myself in front of a class adding _and 3_ on after a delay.  @BarrieEngland ’s answer is along the same lines as mine.  I wonder how he feels about ellipsis here?

Comment: @DanielHarbour: I share your difficulty. I suspect the ellipted form, if that's what it is, is something careful writers would avoid. It's no trouble to write, or even say, _problems_ rather than _problem_.

Comment: I think the OP's question was what *ellipsis* is called. I agree that this example is a borderline case, where you probably shouldn't use ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

It’s either *Please read page 1 and page 2* or *Please read pages 1 and 2* and either *I like number 2 and number 3* or *I like numbers 2 and 3*.

In your last example it’s either *I managed to solve question 6, question 7, question 8 and question 9* or *I managed to solve questions 6, 7, 8 and 9.*